# Activate (switch to) another opened excel book using Python xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I would like to switch to another already opened Excel book.
My scenario:

1. Firstly I create a new book with:

```
xw.Book()
xw.books.active
```

The output:
`<Book [Book7]>`

2. Now I create another new Excel book with:

```
xw.Book()
xw.books.active
```

The ouput: `<Book [Book8]>`

3. Next I would like to activate previous book i.e. Book7
   I tried:

```
xw.books["Book7"]
xw.books.active
```

But it outputs:
`<Book [Book8]>` !!!

How could I reactivate previous book (Book7)? Thank you:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your new workkbok to a variable, then use the `activate` method on it, see: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Book.activate.

```
book1 = xw.Book()
book2 = xw.Book()
book1.activate(steal_focus=True)
```

Up to you if you want `steal_focus` to be `True` or `False` (default).